# How to matrix multiply 2 layers in dl4j

Tags: machine-learning, dl4j

I'm very new to dl4j and I'm struggling to preform basic operations within a graph. 
As an example how would I preform a multiplication of the output of 2 layers. For example in the code below what should the ??? be substituted with? Given that I want to matrix multiply document_output and question_output.

```
   builder.addLayer(document_output,
            RnnProvider().makeLaterLayer(), second_layer_document_rnn)
    builder.addLayer(question_output,
            RnnProvider().makeLaterLayer(), second_layer_question_rnn)
    builder.addVertex(attention,
            ???,
            document_output, question_output
    )
    builder.setOutputs(attention)
```